# Understanding callbacks and promises. Is this correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, callback

So, I am currently learning about callbacks and promises and I keep getting tripped up when watching tutorials. So i thought that I would put it in an example form and see if anyone could tell me if my thinking is correct. I am currently working with MongoDB and Mongoose.

Here is an example piece of code taken from a tutorial. I believe that this is considered a callback?

```
  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "You are not authorized to perform this action.",
      })
    });
```

And then this would be considered a promise?

```
user.save().catch(err => {
   return res.status(400).json({
      error: "You are not authorized."
   })
})
```

Are there any performance advantages of using a promise over a callback or vice versa?

Thank You!

Comment: Read up on the concept of *"callback hell"* and you will start to see how promises are easier to use and very importantly easier to catch errors with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks and promises are different but share some concepts.
A callback is simply a function passed to another function as a parameter where that function can be executed at any time.
for example:

```
function iNeedACallback(callback)
{
  // execute a bunch of code...
  
  // use the callback function provided 
  callBack("a function called 'iNeedACallback'")
}
const callback = (fromFunction) => console.log("I am a callback function called from: " + fromFunction);

// Execute iNeedACallback by passing in the callback
iNeedACallback(callback);
```

The above code is a very simplistic instance of a callback function - now this can either be executed sequentially(like in the example above) or it can be an async operation on the event loop. (for more info about the event loop: [Why do you need to await AJAX calls in JS but not in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206606/why-do-you-need-to-await-ajax-calls-in-js-but-not-in-c/63208841#63208841))

A Promise makes use of callback functions in order to handle async code in a conventional way. The nature of a Promise infers that its some code that will be placed on the event loop as it executed asynchronously and not block any other code while waiting for an operation like a network call.
for example:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
    const text = "i was only called after 2 seconds :(";
    resolve(text);
    }, 2000)
})

promise.then((text) => console.log(text))
console.log("i got called immediately :)")

//Output:
//i got called immediately :)
//i was only called after 2 seconds :(
```

In the above example we give a promise a callback function to execute when an async operation has completed (like a setTimeout) where the most common use cases are network calls like HTTP requests or TCP connections to a database like mongodb.

Back to your original question - your assumption is correct in the sense that your demonstration of a callback and promise is correct, and your question about performance..
Javascript is single threaded so if your callback function is placed on the event loop (which it may or may not be) then it will not block the main execution call stack. Promises are inherently async operation so they will always be placed on the event loop so the performance factor is dependent on the underlying implementation of the callback function - Promises will be async where as some regular callbacks could be sequential and synchronous.